# JadeJS and pre written form values at re-rendering views

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm using Node/Express and Jade to build and App.

I have a POST route that sanitize and validate form input and then save this to a MongoDB. 
If this form input is'nt validated, the route will throw and error and the error handler will re-render this same page...

And here come the problem. In this re-render and want the form values be pre written and ready to be corrected by the user... I don't want a clean form where the user has to re-write everything.

I have tried to submit the req.body (sanitized) data to the re-rendered page, which works. 
But if try to use this data in my Jade view, Node will output and error when this req.body data is **not** defined... Like when you enter this page for the first time, and have'nt entered any wrong inputs yet.

How do i solve this in a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*edit -* Without a code sample I'm not sure if my example is more or less than you need.

If you render the form template immediately within the the form's POST request handler, you probably don't need to involve `req.session`. Just save the appropriate locals and render your template.

If you must redirect or otherwise need to have the values available across multiple requests, you can save them in `req.session` as shown below.

Either way make sure your Jade template handles all cases; in my example I test `if(locals.savedValues)` to decide whether to write defaults or saved values into the form.

Finally if the error is not jade related please paste that error.

---

Use req.session to save the values. Set up a `locals` variable to represent the saved values or null before you render the form.

```
app.get('/form', function(req, res){
  res.locals.savedValues = req.session.savedValues || null;
  res.locals.savedErr = req.session.savedErr || null;
  res.render('form');
});

app.post('/form', function(req, res){
  var values = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
  };
  validateForm(values, function(err, processed){
    if(err){
      req.session.savedValues = processed; 
      req.session.savedErr = err;
      // req.session.savedValues = values, if you dont want to propose changes
      res.redirect('back');
    } else {
      delete req.session.savedValues;
      delete req.session.savedErr;
      res.redirect('/success');
    };
  });
});
```

In your jade template, handle both cases:

```
if(locals.savedErr)
  span.error=locals.savedErr
form(action='form', method='post')
  if(locals.savedValues)
    input#name(type='text')=locals.savedValues.name
    input#email(type='text')=locals.savedValues.email
  else
    input#name(type='text')
    input#email(type='text')
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not that used to work with sessions. Am I right to think that this: `app.use(express.cookieParser());` and this `app.use(express.session();` is everything I need to be able to store values in req.session?

Comment: A short question. You save the vales from req.session to res.locals. You do this to get the values into the jade view, because the req.session are'nt available there?

What about passing the variables to the view like this? Is this wrong?  

`res.render('form', { 
  savedValues: req.session.savedValues || null,
  savedErr: req.session.savedErr || null,
  ...
});`

Comment: You can certainly re-render the form from within the post request, if you do that you shouldn't need the session

Comment: Passing values to the view in the render call works the same as assigning `locals.savedValues`. i usually do the latter for cleaner code (also I sometimes want to delay the `render` call to a later middleware, and `res.locals` is an easy way to save the variables)